# How to isolate CI pipeline per-branch environments in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, networking, namespaces, kubernetes

We are developing a CI/CD pipeline leveraging Docker/Kubernetes in AWS. This topic is touched in [Kubernetes CI/CD pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036853/kubernetes-ci-cd-pipeline).

We want to create (and destroy) a new environment for each SCM branch, since a Git pull request until merge.

We will have a Kubernetes cluster available for that.

During prototyping by the dev team, we came up to Kubernetes namespaces. It looks quite suitable: For each branch, we create a namespace `ns-<issue-id>`.

But that idea was dismissed by dev-ops prototyper, without much explanation, just stating that "we are not doing that because it's complicated due to RBAC". And it's quite hard to get some detailed reasons.

However, for the CI/CD purposes, we need no RBAC - all can run with unlimited privileges and no quotas, we just need a separated network for each environment.

Is using namespaces for such purposes a good idea? I am still not sure after reading [Kubernetes docs on namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/).

If not, is there a better way? Ideally, we would like to avoid using Helm as it a level of complexity we probably don't need.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on an open source project called [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) which is a proposed sub project of the Jenkins foundation aimed at automating CI/CD on Kubernetes using Jenkins and GitOps for promotion.

When you submit a Pull Request we automatically create a *Preview Environment* which is exactly what you describe - a temporary environment which is used to deploy the pull request for validation, testing & approval before the pull request is approved.

We now use Preview Environments all the time for many reasons and are big fans of them! Each Preview Environment is in a separate namespace so you get all the usual RBAC features from Kubernetes with them.

If you're interested here's [a demo of how to automate CI/CD with multiple environments on Kubernetes using GitOps](https://jenkins-x.io/demos/devoxx-uk-2018/) for promotion between environments and Preview Environments on Pull Requests - using Spring Boot and nodejs apps (but we support many languages + frameworks).

Comment: That link is not available. Can you provide it?